# Different types of queues in MSMQ

Tags: msmq

Can anybody explain the different types of queues provided by MSMQ.

Outgoing, private and system queues , what are the functions of them?

Thanks.
Yash

Comment: Check MSDN to find out.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for response, can you please provide the exact link?

Comment: search Google saying `different types of msmq queues`

Answer (score 1):

- Private queues are registered on the local computer, not in the directory service, and typically cannot be located by other Message Queuing applications
- Private queues are accessible only by Message Queuing applications that know the full path name, the direct format name, or the private format name of the queue
- In a domain environment, public queues are queues that are published in Active Directory
- A transactional queue is one that only contains transactional messages, which are messages sent within a transaction

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778799(v=ws.10).aspx